# onRequestPermissionsResult() in Fragment is never called on Oreo

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions

In fragment:

```
requestPermissions(permissionNames, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And handler:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Log.d("Unity", "onRequestPermissionsResult: " + requestCode);
}
```

It show permissions dialog. And `onRequestPermissionsResult` is called on Android 6.0 and 7.0. But on Android 8.0 `onRequestPermissionsResult` is never called.

Have they changed something?

P.S. Target SDK is 27.

Comment: onRequestPermissionsResult(...) will be called in the Activity which handles the Fragment. 
Use requestCode to differentiate between the calls if you have multiple fragments in the same activity.

Comment: Try to use https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions

Comment: @Wasim have they changed it in 8.0, 'cause I ca handle it inside the fragment on 6.0 and 7.0? I don't have access to the main activity, 'cause it is created by Unity.

Comment: @Suvitruf I faced the same problem in 9.0 few days back. By moving the onRequestPermissionsResult(...) to activity, everything started working properly.

Comment: @Wasim I don't have access to Activity, sadly =/

Comment: @Suvitruf: Have a look : https://blog.csdn.net/a598211757/article/details/79883574
Use some translator, i think they are facing the same problem. Hope this may give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

we are going to simplify the process of adding the runtime permissions using **[Dexter](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-easy-runtime-permissions-with-dexter/)** library. Using this library, the permissions can be implemented in a few minutes.